# How does a PCI QSA audit a company?

Tags: appsec, pci-dss, audit

Corporate setups are often complex with data centers in multiple locations, complex ACL's and networks setup between them.

1. How does a PCI auditor actually audit the systems ?
2. How does he get to know about the insides of the network in that
   corporation ?
3. Is there any policy by which the company has to disclose facts to
   the auditor for his work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a company wants to store, transmit or process credit card payments they **must** provide the information the QSA requests. If they deny access to this information, they can be denied the use of VISA and Mastercard payments - which can put a company out of business very quickly!

When I have run pre-PCI audit readiness engagements, I will want full information about every part of the payment data pathway, including physical controls, network infrastructure, team access, authentication, encryption, storage, 3rd parties etc.